# parse a date-time string into a time_t value with spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I need to parse a date-time string like `2012-12-21 12:10:35` into a `time_t` value using `boost::spirit`. here is my code snippet:

```
tc_     =   lexeme[int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_year)=(_1-1900)]>>'-'
                     >>int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_mon)=(_1-1)]>>'-'
                    >>int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_mday)=_1]>>+space
                    >>int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_hour)=_1]>>':'
                     >>int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_min)=_1]>>':'
                    >>int_[phx::ref(tm_.tm_sec)=_1]]    [_val = (long)mktime(&tm_)];
```

where `tc_` is a `qi` rule of type: `qi::rule<Iterator, long(), Skipper>`, `tm_` is a member variable of type `struct tm`.

The code compiles, but doesn't work. it seems that `mktime()` didn't get called at all. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: thanks Andy for editing. I am a newbie here..

Comment: Could I add an attachment? I would like to upload a cpp file to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in c++ 11 vi the regex.
This will be portable and standard, if your compiler is recent enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::regex txt_regex("([0-9]{4})[-]([0-9]{2})[-]([0-9]{2})[ ]([0-9]{2})([:])([0-9]{2})([:])([0-9]{2})");//  
    string strTmp;
    strTmp="2010-12-15 15:25:46";
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex_search( strTmp, match, txt_regex );

    if(regex_match(strTmp,txt_regex))
         cout<<"Ok"<<endl;
    else
    {
    cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
    if ( match.empty() )
    {
         std::cout << "...no more matches" << std::endl;
         return 0;
    }
    for ( auto x : match )
    {
        std::cout << "found: " << x << std::endl;
    }
    string str = match.suffix().str();
    cout <<str <<std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

With this you can display the different parts of the string to display and then fill the structure.

Hope it helps and open for comments as usual (if something is not clear or incomplete).